# How to export video in DaVinci Resolve 18 without (!) reencoding?

Tags: davinci-resolve

I need to cut a video in Resolve 18 and export it. The video is already in the format and encoding I want it to have, I just need to cut out  some parts. After that, I want the file to be saved. Quality is not a priority here, speed is! So I want to simply write the cut file back to an mp4-file within a matter of a few minutes on my 2016 macbook pro (i5). The clip is a simple Zoom-recording in a mp4-container.

Whatever I try to do in the Deliver page, Resolve always starts re-encoding the file, taking 1-2 hours for a clip. How to simply export/write out the cut clip?

Comment: Sadly, that is a must, you can't just "cut out" a part wihtout reeconding. It is possible to sometimes stitch together parts with tools like ffmpeg, but besides that, you'll always have to reencode.

Comment: Thank you, I'm moving to LosslessCut